# How to disable Refresh 2023 in Chrome through command line

Tags: google-chrome, refresh, flags

I would love to disable the feature called Refresh 2023 in Chrome using command line arguments. This feature can be accessed in flags: chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023

I tried `--no-experiments` argument.
I tried all kind of forms of `--disable-feature` argument, going back to the source code of Chromium to sniff out the feature name to disable it.

Nothing worked. The only thing that works programatically is changing the state file of Chrome in AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State by adding a value 3 entry to the dictionary:

```
"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":["chrome-refresh-2023@3"]}
```

Comment: My Ungoogled Chromium 122.0.6261.128 has `--disable-features=ChromeRefresh2023,Journeys` which correspond to the flags `#chrome-refresh-2023` and `#history-journeys`. It does not have the new styling. Unfortunately Chrome 123.0.6312.59 is somehow using the new styling despite disabling `#chrome-refresh-2023`, `#chrome-webui-refresh-2023`, `#chrome-refresh-2023-*` and  `#*-cr23-*`. The `#chrome-refresh-2023` flag previously worked on this browser.